# Проблема нагрузки на БД

Tags: highload, база-данных, mysql

Имеется база данных городов и стран. 
Таблицы этих сущностей соответственно связаны.
При запросе на выборку страны по шаблону %LIKE% и поиску городов, относящихся к стране - проходит секунд 10 в лучшем варианте или вообще браузер говорит в ответных заголовках, что время ожидания истекло (caution provisional headers are shown).
Таблица городов весит 70мб.

Как решать такие вопросы?

Сам запрос:

```
SELECT country.idCountry, country.CountryName, country.CountryName,
  GROUP_CONCAT(CONCAT(citytocountry.idCity, "-", citytocountry.CityName)) AS cities,
  country.CountryFlag, country.CodeCountry, citytocountry.CityName,
  IFNULL(citytocountry.idCity, 0) as idCityFROM (`country`)

LEFT JOIN `citytocountry` ON `citytocountry`.`CountryId` = `country`.`idCountry`
WHERE `CountryName` LIKE 'a%'GROUP BY `country`.`CountryName`
ORDER BY `CountryName` DESC
```

Результат применения команды EXPLAIN:

```
id  select_type table   type    possible_keys   key key_len ref rows    Extra
1   SIMPLE  country ALL NULL    NULL    NULL    NULL    225 Using where; Using temporary; Using filesort
1   SIMPLE  citytocountry   ALL NULL    NULL    NULL    NULL    1167518
```

Comment: Дайте полный запрос сразу.

Comment: Запрос SQL? И еще - можно как-то отследить какие запросы выполняются и время их выполнения?

Comment: @Oleg Ponomarchuk, в mysql для этого надо включить бинлог, но он по понятным причинам будет тормозить систему (плюс пара одновременных запросов приложения собьют всю очередность). По-хорошему в любой фреймворк встроена опция трейсинга запросов.

Comment: Зачем там эти безумные конкатенации?

Comment: а для чего вообще нужен такой запрос? смысл его результата?

Comment: Смысл запроса в том, чтобы за один запрос вытянуть все страны и города по соответствию LIKE.

Comment: Припишите перед `SELECT`'ом `EXPLAIN` и приведите результат.

Comment: В вопросе добавил результат команды EXPLAIN для запроса

Comment: Вижу, что индексы не проставлены, как будет правильно его выставить?

Comment: так а зачем вам выбирать города, пока пользователь не выбрал страну?
как то не логично.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

а зачем все тянуть одним запросом то? пусть юзер выберет сначала страну - а после етого уже по Id страны и города подгрузите аяксом. Юзер введет вам одну букву а в название страны -  вы почти всю таблицу потяните - нецелесообразно